# Set only specific properties as required

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Typescript has `Required<T>` utility type which constructs type consisting of all properties of T set to required. But I want to make only specific properties as required, not all. So I've written my own template(sorry about my C++ lexicon) to do it.

```
interface MyProps {
    foo1?: number;
    foo2?: number;
}

type RequiredProperties<T, RequiredProps extends keyof T> = Required<Pick<T, RequiredProps>> &
  Omit<T, RequiredProps>;

// remove "optional" modifier from the next properties
type requiredProps = 'foo1';
type MakeFoo1Required<T> = RequiredProperties<T, requiredProps>; // <-- got error here

type NewMyProps1 = RequiredProperties<MyProps, requiredProps>; // <-- yes, it works fine
type NewMyProps2 = MakeFoo1Required<MyProps>; // <-- but I wanna to create it through the alias
```

It works fine, but I got a tsc error

> Type '"foo1"' does not satisfy the constraint 'keyof T'.

It happens because tsc does not know that "foo1" is a keyof T.

So I wonder is there a way to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) requiring `T` to have `requiredProps`:

```
type MakeFoo1Required<T extends { [K in requiredProps]?: any }> = RequiredProperties<T, requiredProps>;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8AKUD2AHAZ2QG8BYAKGSuRhxwEYB%20ALmRAFcBbAI2gG4K1GnQBMLNl15QB5AL4UKYdHhQAlCAEd2wKBAAm2fNDDAIBADwAVADTJ1WnfsOFkEAB6QQeogGsI6HBhkSwA%20ZABeO01tXT1zTGAEHytbexinXEIQsIAyQWQAeU5gMBSoh1jnAhCZCgB6OuRdThwANxQAInwTHBA4ABsO5Ba9YBhTKBpcTmQwAAsUEHcwZDxM41MCRWUUXQqM-CJIgHJaBmOZJRU0OD8AMTp6NMc4y1cPCC8iYmQAbQBpZCgJrRF5VAC64jgIHQyFkYUiz0q6ygJjMZT26QMmWqtXIVxQADkIAB3DBVegRcpY5wbdHknG2TFgnE1ZANZDmAC0XOQ6DMthKyBJOCgPiI4yW22uxLJWBxIipqFuEAeDCR%20nMDMONSAA)